# How to define common enum in C++11?

Tags: c++11, enums

So I've got some enum that is defined in one part and I need to use it in multiple other parts of program. As I suppose, there is no extern enums in C++11. So how to use the same defined enum in different units? Sorry for a duplicate or misunderstandings.

Comment: There are enum type definitions and variables that are instances of that enum type.  Which is it you are trying to share?  You can't have an "extern enum *type*" any more than an "extern class *type*" (though an instance of a variable of an enum type can be extern in cases where any other variable type could.)  So you can put your enum *type* in a header file that you include multiple places without concern.  *(If that doesn't solve your problem, could you edit your question to include code specifics?)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be exactly what header files are for:

enum_def.H:

```
 enum class my_enum_type { /* .... */ };
```

file1.C:

```
 #include <enum_def.H>
```

file2.C:

```
 #include <enum_def.H>
```

Comment: Yes...but...underscores in filenames, with capital file extensions that don't discern from C?  You might try `enum-def.hpp` on for a while...definitely looks better if the file ever makes it into a URL bar.  (Consider: `http://example.com/src/enum-def.hpp` vs `http://example.com/Src/enum_def.H`)  See also: [of spaces, underscores, and dashes](http://blog.codinghorror.com/of-spaces-underscores-and-dashes/) from Jeff Atwood

Comment: You must be unaware that there are operating systems which do not get confused by underscores in filenames, and which properly distinguish between uppercase and lowercase filenames. The author of that blog appears to be unaware of that, either.

Comment: Ye, I got it now. But it didn't worked at the first time. Thanks!